# My application design: can I ask for a review?

Tags: design-patterns

I am trying to write a space invaders game in XNA, and have made a class diagram representing the game. It uses the strategy pattern for the bullet. In most examples it shows using an interface, but because I want to add behavior to them, I made it an abstract class. Don't know if that's allowed or not.

Anyways, I wanted to know what your thoughts on it is, and if there could be anything that could be improved. I try to read up a lot on designing, but trying to design always have things that are a bit off from the things you read and you start to wonder if it is correct or not.

I present:

[image: Space Invaders Architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

1. Need more documentation
2. Your inheritance hierarchy seems rather long
3. Read up on [SRP](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html). Seems like Abstract Types are doing a bit too much
4. Also look at [Liskov's substitution](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html) principle. The inheritance hierarchy seems to violate it.

Comment: 1. I got a whole bunch of stuff typed out in documents. Is that what you mean? It contains how things work and what things do, what is needed...

Comment: @TheDude: Not really - but some doc on what the individual responsibilities of each of the classes you have would help and ofcourse the bigger goal :-)

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks, will look into that.

The editor didn't let me put the following when editing 1.: 2. Mmmm.... But how would I give behavior to all three classes (ship, invader, bullet) as well as giving only behavior to only ship and invader? 4. Just read it, but needs to settle so I can try to apply it to my class diagram.

Comment: @TheDude: 4 is more about whether Invader (or for that matter Ship) and AbstractType are interchangeable in various scenarios or not? If not the inheritance is not valid. Inheritance is about having same behaviour not same attributes.

Comment: Took me a while to read up :-) To answer your question, yes, Invader/Ship are interchangeable with AbstractType. Because all three have the same methods/attributes, and none of them add specialized methods. The only thing that they do, is change the inner workings of the Update() method, since each of them have their own speeds etc.